# Javascript complex destructuring in function argument

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am confused seeing a syntax somewhere in my React code as below. Assuming there is some destructuring going on here. Would that be correct ?

```
function xyz ({param1, data: {response, error, classes}, param3}) {

}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. There is destructuring happening in the example. Is there anything else you're having trouble with?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/qofirah/edit?js,console

Comment: Oh...but the way data: {response, error, classes} is evaluated seems somewhat different to normal destucturing....I was thinking in terms of this matching the alias syntax...But in your example above , it looks like there is no aliasing

Comment: @testndtv `data` is being aliased https://davidwalsh.name/nested-destructuring

Comment: Firstly the argument was destructured, there was a data key in it that was an object, then the data object was destructured

Answer (score 0):

Yes destructuring is happening , it may be useful at certain points , but it is better to separate the inputs of the function or use another function for example as params.

Comment: Hmm...I thought destructuring is only when you have multiple variables on the left...e.g. if it was {x, y, z} = obj

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is destructuring.  And specifically, in the example provided in the question:

```
function xyz ({param1, data: {response, error, classes}, param3}) {
    // The following variables are available:
    console.log(param1, response, error, classes, param3);
}
```

This is the same as:

```
function xyz ({param1, data, param3}) {
    let {response, error, classes} = data;
}
```

or without destructuring:

```
function xyz (params) {
    var params1 = params.params1;
    var response = params.data.response;
    var error = params.data.error;
    // ... etc.
}
```

You would likely expect the input to `xyz` to look something like this:

```
{
    param1: 'value',
    data: {
        response: 'value',
        error: 'value',
        classes: 'value',
        // ... (other key/values that are unnecessary in this function)
    },
    param3: 'value',
    // ... (other key/values)

}
```